# file not found exception while trying to read file in netbeans

Tags: java, file, embedded-resource, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I am making an simple application to play sounds in Java. I am able to do that when I keep the audio files in **D:** disk. Here is the code

```
in = new FileInputStream("D:\\"+selectedSounds[position]+".wav");
//Some code for playing audio
```

Then I placed the audio files in same package where the Jframe class is present. But when I run it prompts fileNotFound exception. Can some one tell me why this is happening.

```
in = new FileInputStream(selectedSounds[position]+".wav");
// I have also tried 
    new FileInputStream("./"+selectedSounds[position]+".wav");
```

Here is the file path

[image]

Comment: And this has ..what to do with Swing?  Don't slap a tag on a post simply because that is the GUI toolkit being used.  The same applies for your IDE.  Tags are meant to represent what the *problem* is related to.

Answer (score 4):

Your wave file, contained within the "Source Packages" won't be accessible once the program is packaged as a Jar, as the files will be embedded within the Jar itself and no longer accessible as files.

Instead, you should be using `Class#getResourceAsStream`, for example...

```
try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PlayAudio/" + selectedSounds[position]+".wav")) {
    // You now have an InputStream to your resource, have fun
} catch (IOException | NullPointerException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```